# Will a CNAME redirect subfolders too?

Tags: redirect, dns, web-hosting, cname

Say I have a webserver ***data.mydomain.org***.
Right now the webserver has an index.html with a redirect to ***info.anotherdomain.com***.

In addition to providing a redirect, the server has other content like an images folder and a documents folder. These have to remain operational.
My DNS is GoDaddy. If I get on GoDaddy and add a CNAME of ***info.anotherdomain.com*** to ***data.mydomain.org*** , what happens to the subfolder paths? Will the CNAME make the subfolder paths resolve from lets say ***data.mydomain.org/images/image1.jpg*** to ***info.anotherdomain.com/images/image1.jpg***? Or would subfolders be unaffected?

My goal is to get rid of the current index.html redirect and also have the page at ***info.anotherdomain.com*** come up in the address bar as ***data.mydomain.org***

Answer (score 1):

First of all DNS doesn't redirects it just route. So you will need the CNAME record to could even reach that subdomain.domain.tld.

But the redir, handling of folders and anything else must be performed from the HTTP server side.